# Configuring a proxy for facebook graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, configuration

I'm implementing the facebook graph API but per security reasons I'm not allowed to do a external call in back-end side. In this case what I need to do is to configure a proxy pointing to the facebook graph API, and all graph API calls that my application do should go throughout this proxy.

The facebook graph IP I have been testing is 69.171.234.38, so the proxy conf I have in mind is: destination:69.171.234.38  and port:443.

As this proxy is going to be fixed, I wonder if I can trust in that this IP will remains, I mean, that would be a problem if this IP change since my solution will stop work.

Are the IP used by facebook graph fixed or not?

Comment: I don’t think fixing it to just one IP is a good idea. Besides the fact that this IP might change some day – it might not even be the only one, think of some kind of load-balancing, where requests are directed to different servers according to their current load or something. Can’t you configure your proxy to work with a domain name instead, and have it do the DNS resolution for that on it’s own?

Comment: Thanks CBroe, that's my concern to use a fix IP, but the proxy only point toward an IP. I will talk to IT guy again to see the options I have on this.